# Adding modfiers for non-calibratable sensors

Tags: mysql

I have some 433MHz temperature sensors that I log. One of these is used for the furnace hot water  circuit which goes to my radiators and water heater. Since I cannot recalibrate the sensor, and I am measuing the temperature with a probe mashed in between the insulation and the pipe, I get a measurement that is 10°C off, compared to the analog, properly calibrated sensor which come with the insulation.

I store the values in a MySQL database, and for future use, I prefer to store the raw data. I have a separate table for the sensor metadata.

I want to do something like

```sql
select
  sd.sensorid, 
  sd.unittype,
  sd.value * sm.modifier as realvalue
from
  telldus.sensorData sd 
    left join sensormeta sm
    on sensorData.id = sensormeta.id
group by 
  sm.id,
  unittype
```

(I want to be able to do this, because i think that it might be a multiplier not just an addition)

But this would require me havinb an `int` value - I'd like to store the operator in the field as well. (`*1.1`/`+10`, etc). I don't see this as possible...

### Sensor metadata

| id | type | modifier | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 135 | temperature/humidity | 0 | Soveværelse 1 |
| 136 | temperature/humidity | 0 | Udendørs østvendt |
| 147 | temperature/humidity | +10 | varmtvandskreds |
| 166 | temperature/humidity | 0 | Stue 1 |
| 167 | temperature/humidity | 0 | Soveværelse 2 |

### Sensordata

| id | unittype | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 135 | temperature | 01:00 | 21.2 |
| 135 | humidity | 01:00 | 51 |
| 136 | temperature | 01:00 | -0.3 |
| 147 | temperature | 01:02 | 22.2 |
| 147 | humidity | 01:02 | 41 |
| 166 | temperature | 01:00 | 20.7 |
| 166 | humidity | 01:00 | 31 |
| 167 | temperature | 01:00 | 11.7 |
| 167 | humidity | 01:00 | 64 |
| 199 | temperature | 00:50 | 51.2 |
| 215 | temperature | 01:01 | 4.1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another column to hold the operation.

| id | type | modifier | operation | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 135 | temperature/humidity | 0 | none | Soveværelse 1 |
| 136 | temperature/humidity | 0 | none | Udendørs østvendt |
| 147 | temperature/humidity | 10 | add | varmtvandskreds |
| 166 | temperature/humidity | 1.1 | multiply | Stue 1 |
| 167 | temperature/humidity | 0 | none | Soveværelse 2 |

Then the query will begin:

```
select
  sd.sensorid, 
  sd.unittype,
  CASE sm.operation
    WHEN 'multiply' THEN sd.value * sm.modifier
    WHEN 'add' THEN sd.value + sm.modifier
    ELSE sd.value
  END as realvalue
```